# (Microsoft Academic Knowledge Exploration Service) Help needed in DeployHost procedure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, knowledge-graph, academic-graph

I cannot go further while trying to use MAKES (Microsoft Academic Knowledge Exploration Service) API.

1. I have been referring to the guide document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/knowledge-exploration-service/get-started-create-api-instances)
2. I have the MAKES instances in my Storage Account *(current version: makes/2020-12-07/)*, and all my resource is in East US region *(eastus)*.
3. I am using the up-to-date version of kesm.exe which is downloaded from the current version directory.
4. I requested & granted enough number of Standard DS4v2 Cores *(30)*.
5. So far, I have been successful in creating the image of the resource to be host by inputting the following command line *(I have to mask some information by using "" in the following command lines)*:

   `kesm.exe CreateHostResources --AzureActiveDirectoryDomainName "my active directory" --HostResourceName "my resource name" --MakesPackage https://"my storage".blob.core.windows.net/makes/2020-12-07/ --AzureSubscriptionId "my subscription id" --Region eastus`
6. Being successful in creating the host image as shown above, I went further towards DeployHost part *(in the guide document)*. The command line which I used is as follows:

   `kesm.exe DeployHost --HostName <my host name> --MakesPackage https://"my storage".blob.core.windows.net/makes/2020-12-07/ --MakesHostImageId /subscriptions/"my subscription id"/resourceGroups/"my resource group"/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/"host image name" --AzureSubscriptionId "my subscription id" --AzureActiveDirectoryDomainName "my active directory domain name" --Region eastus --HostMachineSku Standard_DS4_v2 --HostMachineDataDiskSizeInGb 2048`
7. In the command line above, I added 2048 Gb of data disk *(--HostMachineDataDiskSizeInGb 2048)*, by referring to the guide document because I have been receiving "not enough space" error.
8. Following is the successful part of the results from the command line in #6 above:

   ```
    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code HL3V5ZGB6 to authenticate. *(I did the successful authentication)*

    [2020-12-30 3:13:12 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Begin host resource deployment

    [2020-12-30 3:13:12 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Deploying host virtual network resource

    [2020-12-30 3:13:22 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Deploying host public ip address resource

    [2020-12-30 3:13:27 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Deploying host load balancer resource

    [2020-12-30 3:13:30 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Deploying host network security group resource

    [2020-12-30 3:13:36 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0]
          Deploying host virtual machine scaleset resource. AdminUserName: kesm, AdminPassword: "password"
   ```
9. However, I am lost and frustrated by the following errors which continue to generate for multiple pages, right after the successful part above:

   `[2020-12-30 3:18:42 PM] info: Kesm.Kesm[0] Waiting for host to come online`

   `Instance 0: {"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"**Something went wrong downloading kes resources","Data":null**,"InnerException":{"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"**Cannot create/recreate kes resource download folder","Data":null**,"InnerException":{"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"**Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\\Indexes'.","Data":null**,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath, Byte[] securityDescriptor)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)\r\n   at Microsoft.Academic.Knowledge.Core.Service.KesResourceTransferService.DownloadKesResources(String indexFilesUrl, String indexFileKey, String grammarFileUrl, String grammarFileKey, String localResourceDestination, String localResourcePrefix) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Core\\MakesServiceHost\\ServicesHost.Common\\KesResourceTransfer\\KesResourceTransferService.cs:line 162","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2147024893,"Source":"System.IO.FileSystem","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.Academic.Knowledge.Core.Service.KesResourceTransferService.DownloadKesResources(String indexFilesUrl, String indexFileKey, String grammarFileUrl, String grammarFileKey, String localResourceDestination, String localResourcePrefix) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Core\\MakesServiceHost\\ServicesHost.Common\\KesResourceTransfer\\KesResourceTransferService.cs:line 166\r\n   at Microsoft.Academic.Knowledge.Core.Service.KesResourceTransferService.StartKesResourceDownload(String indexFilesUrl, String indexFileKey, String grammarFileUrl, String grammarFileKey, String localResourceDestination, String localResourcePrefix) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Core\\MakesServiceHost\\ServicesHost.Common\\KesResourceTransfer\\KesResourceTransferService.cs:line 141","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2146232800,"Source":"ServiceHost.Common","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Microsoft.Academic.Knowledge.Core.Service.ServiceInitialization.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Core\\MakesServiceHost\\ServiceHost\\Common\\ServiceInitialization.cs:line 43","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2146232800,"Source":"ServiceHost","WatsonBuckets":nulInstance 0: {"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"Something went wrong downloading kes resources","Data":null,"InnerException":{"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"Cannot create/recreate kes resource download folder","Data":null,"InnerException":{"ClassName":"System.Exception","Message":"Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\\Indexes'." *(the error message continues for multiple pages)`
10. After requesting technical assistance, I am re-directed to this page. The Azure specialists say the error is from the MAKES product itself because my kesm commands seem to be in the correct track.

I need any kind of tips to go further with Microsoft Academic materials.

Comment: It looks like your error is `Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\\Indexes` - can you find out where that is being referenced in your code/config?

Comment: @halfer: I agree and I would like to know how I can set up the path. I simply tried to do as the guide document tells me, so I don't have more code other than the command lines in my post.

Comment: @halfer: With the intention to go around the errors about the path, I created VM and VMSS with sufficient data disk through Azure Portal to set up the download path during my trials, only in vain. Then I realized VMSS is being created by the command line in #6, however, the VM which is created during this process did not allow my connection. (I was going to log in using the information given in the last line of #8).  Does MAKES require a "code" form other than the kesm.exe commands like in the guide document?